# EXCEL: How to define excel formula to look date according to last entry above that cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

If anyone can help that would be great.

I'm having a excel sheet that has lots of data filled from 2019 till today.
Since some entries are repeating every now and then and I lose time to filter, find match and copy some of it's data, I'd like to input formula in some cells that would search for that data in table but above that row in which formula is given (i.e. copy data from last same entry). Also, if there is no same entry that it returnes blank so I know that I have to fill the data by hand.
Please note that rows are never fixed, they are usually sorted by one of the columns with date in it and because of that new row entry never comes above last same entry.

If you can give me answer according to example from picture.
Maybe to mention that table is shared through OneDrive as part of Office365.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0dnT.png)

Comment: This is more appropriate on SuperUser -- you'll get a faster answer there

Comment: @Fajka, is Excel VBA out of the question?  If so, then your best bet would probably be using a Pivot Table to process your data for you - then you can make the column for the dates a Filter and it will automatically populate the rest of the columns you specify as other table parameters.  This lets you display a handful of useful columns (if the rest are useless) and then filter the dates out.  If the data is all congruent, you can put a filter on the top row as well and then apply the filter on the date column this way and Excel will filter out the rest.

Comment: A few of questions: 1) Is this a once off requirement or will you have to repeat on a regular basis? 2) Do you want to fully automate or are you happy to do a combination of formula and copy paste (might depend on your answer to Q1)? 3) If those values are not meant to be blank, could you add data validation to prevent this from reoccurring?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.